# Реализация параллельной обработки ленивых коллекций в PLINQ

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, plinq

Допустим, имеется ленивая коллекция типа `IEnumerable` (не важно каким образом она получена), которая будет параллельно обработана оператором `Select` из PLINQ. Для этого будет создан так называемый `Chunk Partition`, который будет обработан N-ым количеством  worker тредов (тут стоит отметить, что коллекция не индексируема, поэтому будет применен именно `Chunk partition`). Каждый такой тред будет обрабатывать `chunk` при помощи итератора типа `ContiguousChunkLazyEnumerator`. Вот отрывок кода `MoveNext` метода `ContiguousChunkLazyEnumerator` класса (из .Net source code):

```
lock (m_sourceSyncLock)
{
// Some .net stuff
    try
    {
        for (; i < mutables.m_nextChunkMaxSize && m_source.MoveNext(); i++)
        {
        // Read the current entry into our buffer.
        chunkBuffer[i] = m_source.Current;
        }
    }
// Some .net stuff
}
```

Как видно из кода, каждый такой итератор работает с расшаренным объектом `m_source` типа `IEnumerator`. Меня интересует следующий вопрос. Как такой подход может давать прирост производительности.  Ведь по сути использование блокировки должно полностью убивать производительность (параллелизм по сути не будет давать преимуществ). И по идее, такой же код исполняемый последовательно одним тредом и без блокировки будет иметь такую же производительность.

Такая реализация не совсем понятна для меня, может быть я что-то не учел? (в многопоточности я еще неопытен, буду благодарен за ответы).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам по себе lock -- это не проблема для производительности многопоточного кода. Проблема -- это когда потоки долго "висят" на lock'е (т.н. high contention). Именно поэтому синхронизируемый участок кода должен выполняться как можно быстрее.

Все, что делает вышеприведенный участок кода под lock'ом -- заполняет новый чанк (`chunkBuffer`) из источника и обновляет внутренние индексы. Это очень быстрый код, поэтому сильного конкурирования потоков на этом участке вы не получите. Даже если несколько потоков и столкнутся на этой секции, ждать каждый из них будет очень недолго.

**Upd**

Да, в случае ленивого и долгого вычисления последовательности код под локом действительно может долго выполняться и вы получите высокую конкуренцию на этом участке кода. Но кроме фазы "извлечения" элементов PLINQ также делает и фазу "вычисления" над этими элементами. И это, как заметил @kmv в комментариях, главная его ответственность. PLINQ в первую очередь предназначен для параллелизации некоторых действий над элементами. И на этой фазе вы по-прежнему получите прирост производительности относительно однопоточного варианта. Конечно, если в вашем случае вычисление элементов последовательности намного тяжелее дальнейших действий, то итоговый прирост будет небольшим.

Comment: Вот именно, интересна ситуация когда потоки виснят на блокировке. Ведь на самом деле, вычисление элемента коллекции может быть дорогой операцией. Код внутри блокировки может быть долгим. Простой пример, когда у меня при вычислении элемента коллекции приходится полностью вычислять какое-то дерево, связанное с этим элементом

Comment: Синхронизируемый код выполняет две операции `MoveNext` и `Current`. Каждая из операций может потребовать много времени на вычисление

Comment: @LmTinyToon извлечение элементов из последовательности - это не зона ответственности PLINQ. Его ответственность - произвести вычисления над (уже извлеченными) элементами последовательности

Comment: @LmTinyToon самое главное-то в вопросе и пропустил :). Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Если кратко, то PLINQ параллелит действия над последовательностью, а не вычисление самой последовательности.

В любом случае, интерфейс `IEnumerable` не позволяет распараллелить себя by design, это принципиально последовательный интерфейс. Если у вас элементы последовательности вычисляются слишком долго - значит, вы зря ожидаете выгод от PLINQ.

Надо или менять архитектуру, убирая из нее ту самую последовательность с долгим вычислением - или отказываться от "однородной" параллельности в пользу конвейера. Во втором случае вам поможет библиотека Tpl Dataflow или класс [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Идея конвейера - в том, чтобы последовательность вычислял один поток, а операции над элементами производил уже другой или другие.

Comment: Но ведь выполнение действия над последовательностью должно затрагивать вычисление элементов последовательности. Вычисление ведь в случае коллекций отложенное.

Comment: @LmTinyToon да, оно отложенное - но от этого не перестает быть последовательным.

Comment: Интересное упоминание о DataFlow, надо посмотреть